# Set associated to Hasse diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I was asked to write all pairs associated to the following Hasse diagram:

[image]

I'm very new to the topic and I have a few doubts.

First of all, the diagram depicts an unspecified order relation $\preceq$. As I understand it, the diagram flows upwards, connecting $x$ to $y$ if  $y$ covers $x$; this is, if $x \preceq y$ and for all $c$ not equal to $x , y$, $x \preceq c \implies \neg (c \preceq y)$.

Of course, from this follows that $\{(a, d), (b, d), (d, e), (e, g), (c, f), (f, g) \}$  are pairs, because $d$ covers $a$ and $b$, $e$ covers $d$, etc. What I'm confused about is what I am not explicitely told.

For example, both $c$ and $f$ do not cover $a$. This might mean $c \preceq d$ while being some $q$ such that $c \preceq q$ and $q \preceq a$, or it might mean $\neg (c \preceq a)$.

In other words, there are two possibilities for every pair of non-connected dots, and (I think) there is no way of knowing which is true.

Being that the case, how am I supposed to write all pairs associated to the diagram above? There are relations (for example, $(a, f)$) that could or could not be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

partial order relations are transitive, antisymmetric, and reflexive. So first you should have all pairs $\{(a,a),(b,b), (c,c),(d,d),(e,e),(f,f),(g,g)\}$ because of reflexivity.

Then you have pairs that you wrote. $\{(a,d),(b,d),(d,e),(e,g),(c,f),(f,g)\}$ this are antisymetric. But you also cannot forget pairs witch are transitive. This mean that $a⪯d \wedge d⪯e $ you also has to have $a⪯e$, because of a transitivity.

So by transitivity you have pairs $\{(a,e),(a,g), (d,g),(c,g),(b,e),(b,g)\}$

Your final answer should be $\{(a,a),(b,b), (c,c),(d,d),(e,e),(f,f),(g,g), (a,d),(b,d),(d,e),(e,g),(c,f),(f,g),(a,e),(a,g), (d,g),(c,g),(b,e),(b,g)\}$.

Comment: A direct and clear answer. Much appreciated!